# Fahren and Abfahren-- Kommen and Ankommen

Tags: perfect-tense

I wonder the difference between fahren and abfahren moreover kommen and ankommen .

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This is an exercise how to build the participle from the infinitive of separable verbs, and you had it right.

Comment: I wonder the difference between fahren and abfahren  , kommen and ankommen

Comment: Then edit your question. Homework does not suit this forum.

Comment: Now you can tell us why a dictionary did not help you: [fahren](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/fahren), [abfahren](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/abfahren), [kommen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/kommen), [ankommen](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/ankommen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. „fahren“ = to drive (if you’re steering), otherwise „ ride“ or just „go“; „abfahren“ ist a special variation that is mostly used in the sense of „leaving“.
2. „kommen“ = to come; „ankommen“ = to arrive